# asp.net application suddenly stopped reading newly created records

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, telerik-grid, iis-10

My web application is created using asp.net 4.0, with sql server express. I am using telerik grid control to display data. Suddenly i observe that, i am able to create records, checked from back end, but these newly created records are not getting fetched. Existing records are getting displayed in the telerik grid.
Following are the details in which this application is setup,
OS is Windows 10 x64 pro, Sql Server Express 2008 R2, IIS 10.

Note: same application and database setup in a different laptop is working fine.

Comment: I think you need to rebind the telerik grid with latest data fetch.

Comment: are you testing in internet explorer?

Comment: Can you post the code where you're loading the data and the markup where the control is set up?

Comment: same application when setup in another laptop is working fine. and i have used IE, firefox and chrome to test